# Where can I find phpmyadmin login page?

Tags: phpmyadmin

This guide https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/phpmyadmin.html asks me to check localhost/phpmyadmin but I have installed phpmyadmin on a cloud server where I have installed Ubuntu. I can access redmine installed at IPAdress/redmine but can't access phpMyadmin the same way. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed phpMyAdmin on a remote computer, you need to use the address of the remote computer instead of `localhost`. Using your example of redmine, you need to enter IPAddress/phpmyadmin into your browser.

Comment: Yes. When I did that, it shows 404 error.. Requested URL not found on that server

Comment: Try `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` to make Apache restart itself and re-read the configuration files.

Comment: Bids nothing, I guess everyone is here to help. Might consider to upvote my comment above and accept my answer so that future people searching on this matter will see that this was the problem.

Comment: it depends  on phpmyadmin and its permissions to connect to mysql from remote computer

Answer (score 0):

**Login to your server via ssh and run this line below**

```
 ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin
```

Found this from this thread 
http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=34823

Answer (score -1):

$ gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Include the following line at the bottom of the file, save and quit.

$ Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf